# Usage of static block vs. direct static variable initialization

Tags: java, static

Suppose, I have a data access layer class, where I want to specify database connection parameters. Usually, I do it as static variables and initialize it right after definition, e.g. see `DB_NAME` variable case.

Performing code review, I paid attention that sometimes such logic is implemented with a static block, e.g. see `DB_HOST` variable case.

```java
public class DAL {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "MY_DB";
    private static final String DB_USER = "DB_ADMIN";
    private static final String DB_HOST;

    static {
        DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    }
}
```

**The questions:**

1. Is there any benefit from using a static block in such specific scenario?
2. When should I prefer to use a static block over a regular static variable initialization?

P.S. I found a similar question on SO: [Why use static blocks over initializing instance variables directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056895/why-use-static-blocks-over-initializing-instance-variables-directly), but if you have something to add, you're welcome.

Comment: A static block is often used to fill a constant map; when a single expression is not feasible. Above it could only be a self-invented stylistic issue, maybe DB_HOST is intended to be replaced or always fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In such scenario it only obstructs code readability. No benefits.
2. You should use static block only if static field initialization is not enough (e.g. you should call several methods, or this methods throw checked exceptions).

Just created 2 sample classes:

```
public class Static {
    public static String s = "qwe";
}
```

---

```
public class StaticBlock {
    public static String s;
    static {
        s = "qwe";
    }
}
```

And using `javap -c` we can see bytecodes of this classes:

```
Compiled from "Static.java"
public class Static {
  public static java.lang.String s;

  public Static();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String qwe
       2: putstatic     #3                  // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
       5: return
}
```

---

```
Compiled from "StaticBlock.java"
public class StaticBlock {
  public static java.lang.String s;

  public StaticBlock();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String qwe
       2: putstatic     #3                  // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
       5: return
}
```

As you can see, bytecodes are identical :)

**UPD**: Its getting more interesting! If we add `final` modifier to our static field, bytecodes will be different.

```
public class Static {
    public static final String s = "qwe";
}
```

---

```
public class StaticBlock {
    public static final String s;
    static {
        s = "qwe";
    }
}
```

We will have:

```
Compiled from "Static.java"
public class Static {
  public static final java.lang.String s;

  public Static();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

---

```
Compiled from "StaticBlock.java"
public class StaticBlock {
  public static final java.lang.String s;

  public StaticBlock();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String qwe
       2: putstatic     #3                  // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
       5: return
}
```

I found a little bit of explanation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354412/do-java-finals-help-the-compiler-create-more-efficient-bytecode).

Comment: Regarding _«You should use static block only if static field initialization is not enough»_, in such cases I write a method, which returns a desired value for the static variable. Is usage a static block a better alternative than approach I use?

Comment: @MikeB. There is one major difference between them: static block is called only once by VM; static method could be called several times by users. 
Basically, in case of method, you just 'cache' method's result into variable. If this result is constant, there is no sense calling this method again ever, because you already have computed value in variable (and in this case introducing method could confuse developers, so they can call this method, instead of using variable).  If method result is not constant and it makes sense to call this method later on, its absolutely ok to have this method)

Comment: @MikeB. also take a look at another opinions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618551/static-block-vs-private-static-method-for-static-member-initialization